# Can anyone explain the meaning of "Hegelian Essence"

Tags: hegel, marx, marxism, secondary-literature

I've been reading Terry Eagleton's Marxist critique of the bronte's and Eagleton writes that Catherine "reifies Heathcliff to a Hegelian essence, sublimely untainted by empirical fact".

I can't seem to find any simplified explanations of the concept of "Hegelian essence", so any help with understanding this concept would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/is-there-a-parallel-between-hegelian-essence-and-kantian-concept) for details about Hegel's notion of *essence*.

Comment: In the context of Bronte's novel, it means noting. The "pseudo-marxian" jargon: "reifies Heathcliff to a Hegelian essence", can mean that Catherine sees [Heathcliff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathcliff_(Wuthering_Heights)) as a sort of mytical character, half hero-half demon.

Comment: Thanks Mauro Allegranza, the above post was very useful. Your interpretation that Catherine views Heathcliff as a mythical character makes sense to me, as Heathcliff's 'essence' seems to be the idea of Heathcliff rather than his physical manifestation, many thanks :)

Comment: See some [lines above](https://books.google.it/books?id=PraDDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA102) : "the timeless metaphysical idea Heathcliff embodies." And after: "he would rather enact his essence..." Thus IMO, as per post linked, it is only "essence"; the Hegelian concept has no specific differences with the traditional (Aristotelian) notion that can be relevant for this context.